# Excel - if cell contains text in a list then return value of another cell

Tags: excel, function, indexing, match, formula

I have 3 columns:

A - Lookup item
B - List
C - Link
D - formula goes here

I want to search column B for the text in each cell in column A.

For example, A2="bread" and with column B it has B2="some bread" and would return TRUE. If it's TRUE, then I want to return the value in C2="abc".

Another example, A3="eggs" and B3="egg" would return FALSE. But B4="eggs" and would return TRUE, then I want to return value in D3="ghi".

Here's an image to illustrate:

[image]

I can find the word in column A to any in the list in column be with this formula:

```
=if(countif($B$2:$B$6,"*"&A2&"*")>0,true,false)
```

But I can't get the right mix of INDEX and MATCH to return the contents in column C when needed. I think I need a mix of INDEX with ROW instead of MATCH.

The issue with MATCH is the 3rd argument is [match_type] which is "1= exact or next smallest(default)", "0=exact match", "-1 = exact or next largest".

Version: Excel 2016
(also would like it to work in Google Sheets but not required)

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Excel 2016. Also added it to the bottom of the question. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

Try `Match()` function with wildcard matching.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH("*"&A2&"*",$B$2:$B$6,0)),FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: If you have `EXCEL-365` then can use `XLOOKUP()` with wildcard match mode.

Comment: Oh, this might work! I'm testing to see if it covers all use cases. Will report back.